# What is the purpose of CascadeType.MERGE in Many to Many relationships?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, orm, spring-data

Suppose we have a `Post` class with a tags reference that is a `List`:like this ([Original source](https://vladmihalcea.com/the-best-way-to-use-the-manytomany-annotation-with-jpa-and-hibernate/)):

```
@ManyToMany(cascade = { 
    CascadeType.PERSIST, 
    CascadeType.MERGE
})
@JoinTable(name = "post_tag",
    joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "post_id"),
    inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "tag_id")
)
private List<Tag> tags = new ArrayList<>();
```

Why do we need `CascadeType.MERGE`?  Is this in the event that, for example, we remove tags from the list and then we persist the post, thus we want the result to "Merge" (Unmap the tags from the post in the many to many join table) with the current database state?

Comment: This type question already answered here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4935095/jpa-hibernate-many-to-many-cascading but your is just modifiable confusing double ?? mark for your knowledge.

Comment: Well, let me see, if you are attaching a detached object (which was subsequently modified whilst detached) by calling `em.merge` and want to cascade the merge to related objects, perhaps you need to know whether to merge a field? which applies to 1-1, 1-N, N-1, M-N all equally. Any basic JPA doc would tell you this