# How to send only a list of IDs in many-to-many spring boot JPA POST request instead of sending the full object's data

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa, many-to-many

I have 2 DTOs "OrderItem" and "Ingredient", both classes has **@ManyToMany** annotation:

```
@Entity
@Table
@NoArgsConstructor
@Data
public class OrderItem {

    private @Id @GeneratedValue @NotNull long id;

    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    @JoinColumn(nullable = false)
    @OnDelete(action = OnDeleteAction.CASCADE)
    private Order order;

    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    @JoinColumn(nullable = false)
    @OnDelete(action = OnDeleteAction.CASCADE)
    private Food food;

    private int quantity;

    @ManyToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinTable(
            name = "order_item_ingredient",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "order_item_id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "ingredient_name")
    )
    private Set<Ingredient> ingredients = new HashSet<>();
}
```

---

```
@Entity
@Table
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Ingredient {
    private @Id String ingredientName;
    private float basePrice;
    private boolean addable;
    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "ingredients",cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    private Set<Food> foods= new HashSet<>();

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "ingredients",cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    private Set<OrderItem> orderItems= new HashSet<>();

    public Ingredient(String ingredientName, float basePrice, boolean addable) {
        this.ingredientName = ingredientName.toLowerCase();
        this.basePrice = basePrice;
        this.addable = addable;
    }
}
```

And I'm looking to add a new OrderItem using a POST request using the following @PostMapping controller function:

```
@PostMapping("{id}/orderItem")
public ResponseEntity<OrderItem> createMenuItem(
        @PathVariable(value = "id") Long orderId,
        @RequestBody OrderItem orderItem) {

    Order order = orderService.getOrder(orderId)
            .orElseThrow(() -> new ResourceNotFoundException("order '" + orderId + "' is not found"));

    orderItem.setOrder(order);
    orderItemRepository.save(orderItem);

    return new ResponseEntity<>(orderItem, HttpStatus.CREATED);
}
```

When I send a post request to **localhost:8080/1/orderItem** with the following body:

```
{
    "order":"1",
    "food":"burger",
    "quantity":"1"
}
```

It works fine and a new order_item database record is created, but when I send the same request with the following body:

```
{
    "order":"1",
    "food":"burger",
    "quantity":"1",
    "ingredients": [{"ingredientName":"leaf"}]
}
```

It fails and gives the following SQL error:

```
java.sql.SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Duplicate entry 'leaf' for key 'ingredient.PRIMARY'
```

I know that this record already exists, but how do I tell Spring Boot that I want it to look for an existing Ingredient instead of trying to create a new one?

I have an ugly solution in my mind, and that is to send the **OrderItem** object alongside a list of strings where each element represents a primary key for **Ingredient** class, then iterate through that list element by element calling the repository to get the **Ingredient** object then manually add it to **OrderItem.ingredients**, but I'm sure that is not the best solution out there.

Answer (score 0):

Being defined on the `OrderItem` class, the relation `ingredients` is considered as a composition on the cascading strategy point of view. Therefore, the `CascadeType.ALL` implies the attempt to create the ingredient.
To avoid this, you can change the direction of this relation reverse the mappedBy information.
But then again, if you keep a `CascadeType.ALL` on the ingredient side, you will be in trouble if you create an ingredient with an existing `orderItem`. You can win on both sides an use `CascadeType.ALL`.

check [JPA Hibernate many-to-many cascading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4935095/jpa-hibernate-many-to-many-cascading)

Answer (score 0):

I have 2 DTOs "user" and "role", both classes has @ManyToMany annotation:

```
@Entity
public class User {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    private String name;
    // Other attributes
    
    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(
        name = "user_role",
        joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_id"),
        inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "role_id")
    )
    private Set<Role> roles = new HashSet<>();
    // Getters and Setters
}

@Entity
public class Role {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    private String name;
    // Other attributes
    
    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "roles")
    private Set<User> users = new HashSet<>();
    // Getters and Setters
}
```

And I'm looking to add a new UserRole using a POST request using the following @PostMapping controller function:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/users")
public class UserController {

    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository; // Assuming UserRepository is a Spring Data JPA repository for User entity

    @Autowired
    private RoleRepository roleRepository;

// Endpoint to add roles to a user
    @PostMapping("/{userId}/roles")
    public ResponseEntity<User> addRolesToUser(@PathVariable Long userId, @RequestBody List<Long> roleIds) {
        Optional<User> user = userRepository.findById(userId);
        if (user.isPresent()) {
            Set<Role> roles = new HashSet<>();
            for (Long roleId : roleIds) {
                Optional<Role> role = roleRepository.findById(roleId);
                if (role.isPresent()) {
                    roles.add(role.get());
                }
            }
            user.get().getRoles().addAll(roles);
            userRepository.save(user.get());
            return ResponseEntity.ok(user.get());
        } else {
            return ResponseEntity.notFound().build();
        }
    }

    // Endpoint to remove roles from a user
    @DeleteMapping("/{userId}/roles/{roleId}")
    public ResponseEntity<User> removeRoleFromUser(@PathVariable Long userId, @PathVariable Long roleId) {
        Optional<User> user = userRepository.findById(userId);
        Optional<Role> role = roleRepository.findById(roleId);
        if (user.isPresent() && role.isPresent()) {
            user.get().getRoles().remove(role.get());
            userRepository.save(user.get());
            return ResponseEntity.ok(user.get());
        } else {
            return ResponseEntity.notFound().build();
        }
    }
}
```

postman request

```
POST localhost:8080/users/{userId}/roles
In body raw- json
[1,2,3]
```

Output:
Record insert successfully

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/41Edc.png)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).