# How to update ManyToMany relations in JPA with Spring Boot 3

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I'm struggeling with updating the many to many relations of an entity.
I've created a simple book entity:

```java
@Entity
public class Book {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  @Column(name = "id", nullable = false)
  private Integer id;

  @ManyToMany
  @JoinTable(name = "book_character",
      joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "book_id"),
      inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "character_id"))
  private Set<Character> characters = new LinkedHashSet<>();

  // getters and setters
}
```

Each book can have multiple characters and every character can appear in multiple books.

```java
@Entity
public class Character {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  @Column(name = "id", nullable = false)
  private Integer id;

  @Size(max = 200)
  @NotNull
  @Column(name = "name", nullable = false, length = 200)
  private String name;

  // getters and setters
}
```

To create, read, save, and delete entities I'm using Springs repository interfaces.

```java
@Repository
interface BookRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<Book, Integer>, ListCrudRepository<Book, Integer> {
}

@Repository
public interface CharacterRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<Character, Integer>, ListCrudRepository<Character, Integer> {
}
```

To test it I'm using an in memory h2 database.

```java
@DataJpaTest
public class JpaTest {

  @Autowired
  private BookRepository bookRepository;

  @Autowired
  private CharacterRepository characterRepository;

  @Test
  public void test() {
    final Character character = createCharacter();
    final Book book = createBook(character);
    this.characterRepository.delete(character);

    final Optional<Character> characterOptional = this.characterRepository.findById(character.getId());
    assertTrue(characterOptional.isEmpty());

    final Optional<Book> bookOptional = this.bookRepository.findById(book.getId());
    assertTrue(bookOptional.get().getCharacters().isEmpty());
  }

  private Character createCharacter() {
    final Character character = new Character();
    character.setName("John Doe");
    return this.characterRepository.save(character);
  }

  private Book createBook(final Character character) {
    final Book book = new Book();
    book.getCharacters().add(character);
    return this.bookRepository.save(book);
  }

}
```

Now I have the following problem:
When I add a new character and add a new book referencing this character, I can delete the character. But the book still contains the character, that does not exist anymore.

```java
final Optional<Character> characterOptional = this.characterRepository.findById(character.getId());
assertTrue(characterOptional.isEmpty()); // succuss

final Optional<Book> bookOptional = this.bookRepository.findById(book.getId());
assertTrue(bookOptional.get().getCharacters().isEmpty()); // fails
```

What I don't understannd is, that the character can be deleted successfully, while having a reference in the book.
I tried deleting the reference manually by ...

```java
@Modifying
@Query("delete from BookCharacter bc where bc.character.id = :characterId")
void deleteCharacterReference(@Param("characterId") int characterId);
```

... but the result stays the same.

Can anyone explain please.

**Update**

I updated my test with flushing after deleting the character. The character is still present in the character list of the book.

```java
  @Test
  public void test() {
    final Character character = createCharacter();
    final Book book = createBook(character);

    final int count = this.bookRepository.deleteCharacterReference(character.getId());
    this.characterRepository.delete(character);
    this.characterRepository.flush();

    final Optional<Character> characterOptional = this.characterRepository.findById(character.getId());
    assertTrue(characterOptional.isEmpty());
    assertEquals(1, count);

    final Optional<Book> bookOptional = this.bookRepository.findById(book.getId());
    assertTrue(bookOptional.isPresent());
    assertTrue(bookOptional.get().getCharacters().isEmpty()); // still fails
  }
```

Comment: Does [JPA Hibernate many-to-many cascading](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4935095) help?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, Using *ManyToMany* means that both entities are not tightly coupled with each other. So, when you delete a character, It can be still related to other books, And vise versa.

So, Either you choose a single owner of the relation and only use it for relationship removal (not entity removal), Or if you really have the use-case of removing character and also remove its relations with all books, You can use *BiDirectional ManyToMany* and use *@PreRemove* inside the Character to remove all related books:

```
@PreRemove
private void removeBookAssociations() {
   for (Book book: this.books) {
       book.getCharacters().remove(this);
   }
}
```

References:

- https://www.baeldung.com/jpa-remove-entity-many-to-many
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/1089008

Answer (score 0):

> I am using JpaRepository for Book and Character Repositories to be able to manually `flush()` to database.

**SOME CONTEXT** : by calling flush() immediately after delete

```
this.characterRepository.delete(character);
this.characterRepository.flush();
```

will throw **DataIntegrityViolationException** because we are trying to remove a `Character` that is referenced by a `foreign-key` from `Book_Character` table.

**Answer:**

so we have to remove the Book_Character table's row first then remove the Character row

```
book.getCharacters().remove(character);
this.characterRepository.delete(character);
```

I highly recommend that you read [associations](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/6.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#associations) section of hibernate docs. or at least the [uni-directional @ManyToMany](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/6.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#associations-many-to-many) section.

Comment: I updated my test accordingly. But the book entity still contains the delete character,

Comment: the flush() part was me giving context so that you can debug it and see the exception. the answer is to use the owning side (the book) and remove the child side (character) from the collection. please reread the second code block from my answer. and also consider reading the recommended links